# Help with understanding third sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

In the below I am unsure of my understanding of the third sentence.

> 「実は、うちのチーム、エースのアタッカーとセッターがうまくいってないんだよねぇ」
>
> To tell the truth, our team's ace attacker and setter aren't getting
> along well.
>
> 「バレーでアタッカーとセッターがうまくいってないってのは、野球で言えばピッチャーとキャッチャーがいがみ合ってるのと同じ位危うい状況なのさ」
>
> An attacker and setter not getting along well in volleyball is as bad
> a situation as a pitcher and a catcher not getting along well in
> baseball.
>
> 「いまアタッカーの人が絶好調とは言えない状態で、ミスする度にセッターを責めているというか」
>
> At the moment, the attacker is not in their best form, and she is
> blaming the setter every time she makes a mistake.
>
> 「確かにセッターの子は初心者だからいつも完璧なトスを上げられてる訳じゃないんだけどね」
>
> It's true though that the setter is a beginner so she doesn't always
> set the perfect ball.

---

Is the third sentence saying that the attacker isn't playing well (and therefore making mistakes), and then blaming the setter for them?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're essentially asking who is the subject of ミスする. Judging from the context, I agree that the subject of ミスする is the attacker, not the setter. This is because this part is preceded by アタッカーの人が絶好調とは言えない状態で. It's natural to assume all the three predicative phrases in the sentence (絶好調とは言えない状態だ, ミスする, 責めている) share the common subject.